# C++: overloading mathematical operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am looking to overload, let's say, the addition operator and have it add two objects of the same class.  When I declare this "operator+" prototype function in the class declaration in the header file, I pass in both objects as parameters.  I get a compiler error saying that "binary 'operator +' has too many parameters".  I was searching around for an answer online and found out that declaring an inline function just outside the class declaration in the header file compiled out.  I'm wondering what I was doing wrong or if I'm missing something here.  Here is the code I am using in the header file.

```
class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    double weight;
public:
    Person::Person();                           //default constructor       
    Person::~Person();                           //default desctructor
    Person operator+(Person r, Person i);
};
```

This compiles with the error I mentioned above.  Below is the code that compiles fine.

```
class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    double weight;
public:
    Person::Person();                           //default constructor       
    Person::~Person();                           //default desctructor
};
inline Person operator+(Person r, Person i)
{
return Person(0,0); 
}
```

Comment: Note that adding persons is not an operation everybody is familiar with, so overloading `operator+()` most likely does not make sense for it. See my answer for more details. It's a good question, though, +1 from me.

Comment: I was using a Person class just for this example to make it simple enough to get my point across.  I'm actually using a Complex number class and didn't want to get into a lengthy discussion on why I'm not using the Complex class that's already created.

Comment: ...which got you into the discussion whether `operator+()` makes sense for a `Person` class. `:)` Yep, for a class `Complex` overloading arithmetical operators makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you declare `oparator+` as an instance function then the first argument is being passed as `this` object and thus you need only one more argument. Read this for more info, in particular try to understand the `const` concept:

http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

The best approach as advised in the referenced artice is:

```
class Person
{
    ...
    Person &operator+=(const Person &i);
    const Person operator+(const Person &i) const;
    ...
};

Person &Person::operator+=(const Person &i) {
    ...   // Do the compound assignment work.
    return *this;
}

const Person Person::operator+(const Person &i) const {    
    Person result = *this;     // Make a copy of myself.  Same as MyClass result(*this);
    result += i;            // Use += to add other to the copy.
    return result;              // All done!
}
```

if you decide to use `const` version remember that you will only be able to call `const` methods on `this` and `i` references. This is the preferred way.

The article I referenced to explains the idea of overloading `+=` first and then defining `+` using `+=` in more details. This is a good idea since `+=` operator must be separately overloaded.

Additionally - David Rodríguez suggests `operator+` to be implemented as a free function regardless of the presence of += .

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  I was struggling with this concept for a fews days.  Guess I just haven't gotten enough sleep.  Now it makes total sense.

Comment: -1 from me for discouraging the use of `const`. Using `const` is, IMO, one of the most powerful tools in a C++ programmer's toolbox, while at the same time being one you are very unlikely to hurt yourself with. It's one of the greatest features of the language and its use should be encouraged wherever possible.

Comment: discouraging? Interesting interpretation. -1 ? Even more interesting.

Comment: discouraging const/encouraging to use the non-const version... that is a horrible advice. Semantically `a+b` should not modify neither `a` nor `b`, so it makes the most sense to have it `const`. I found interesting the last edit you did (implement `+` in terms of `+=`, but still miss suggesting `+` to be implemented as a free function regardless of the presence of `+=`)

Comment: I hope you like this version better.

Comment: @sbi: Const is goddamn annoying. I spend more time crapping around marking things const when they never need to be than any benefit const could ever give. I'd be much happier if const never existed. In addition, there's no sense or value in returning a const rvalue.

Comment: @DeadMG returning a const prevents code like `Person a,b,c; (a+b) = c;`, so it's not completely nonsensical, but it is rather unlikely than anyone would make the sorts of error it prevents.

Comment: No, that's illegal even with non-const rvalues. `int a, b, c; (a + b) = c;` is an error. The left-hand of operator= must be an lvalue.

Comment: @DeadMG: Pete's code is not forbidden, yours is. For UDT's you can invoke non-`const` functions on rvalues, which includes calling the assignment operator. Assignment to rvalues of built-ins is forbidden.

Comment: @DeadMG: More than a decade ago, when I had joined a new company and was assigned to a project, I found that I couldn't call some member function from my `const`-correct code because someone had forgotten to make it `const`. So I went in and made it `const` - just to discover that it called three other functions two of which were missing a `const`. So I went in... I had my new co-workers laughing at me while I hunted through a several-10kLoC codebase and added `const` - until I showed them some of the very embarrassing errors the compiler had found me with the help of `const`. Incidentally...

Comment: ...a few hard to reproduce bugs that nobody ever had even tried to find were gone afterwards. In a meeting it was then decided that developers are to add `const` wherever and whenever possible. The moral of this? __Never underestimate `const`.__

Comment: @sbi: I guess it's true that I mostly code for myself instead of in such an environment. I still think that it could use a greater degree of automation - for example, automatically labelling functions const when appropriate. Edit: Distinctions between UDTs and primitives is phail. I thought C++ ditched all of those.

Comment: @sbi - thx, I was wondering whether you remember about this detail ;)

Answer (score 6):

Every member function has an implicit first argument: `this`. This is also true for operators. Therefor, if you want to make `operator+()` a member, it must only take one argument, the right operand, because the left operand already is `this`.

However, for binary operators that can be either a member function or a free function, my rule of thumb is to make those a free function which treat their arguments symmetrically (`operator+()` doesn't change either of its operands), and make those a member function which don't (`operator+=()` changes its left operand, but not its right).
Further, for all arithmetical operators, there's a nice pattern to implement them based on their combined assignment versions. That is, `operator+()` would be based on `operator+=()`, `-` based on `-=` etc.
Add to this that you don't want to needlessly copy class objects, but usually want them to be passed per `const` reference.

Based on this, my canonical versions of `operator+` would be:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person& operator+=(const Person& i)
    {
      // whatever
      return *this;
    }
};

inline Person operator+(Person lhs, const Person& rhs)
{
  lhs += rhs; // note: lhs passed per copy
  return lhs;
}
```

***However.*** What's probably the most important rule of thumb regarding operator overloading is this: ***Don't do it***. This might sound paradoxical, but most often named functions are a lot better than operators, because the latter make the code *less* readable than normal functions would. And when writing code, *readability should be the most important aspect*. ***Unless an operators has a clear and undisputed meaning in the application domain, don't overload it*** for a class.
In your example there certainly is *no clean and undisputed* meaning of operator `+` applied to two persons. What does it mean in the real world to add to persons? (The first meaning I could think of wouldn't have a single person as a result, but an array of persons.`:)`)
So, unless overloading this operator for your `Person` class is a homework assignment, I would strongly advice against it. (And if it is an assignment, I'd blame the teacher for finding such a bad example.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for a working += in a class.

```
Vector3D& operator+=( const Vector3D& other ) {
        x+=other.x;
        y+=other.y;
        z+=other.z;
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to take a vector by copy.

Comment: I wanted to show how he gets a working += . This version works, but ok, now its a reference to make ppl happy.

Comment: (You should properly attribute comments directed at someone, otherwise they don't show up in their list of responses and are likely to be overseen.) Good, I have removed my down-vote. Note that, when you answer a question, you usually are effectively teaching someone to do something they don't know how to do. If you omit something you don't think is relevant to the answer, they won't learn to regard it.

Comment: @sbi Ok, I will take this into account when writing my next answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read the best practice is to declare `operator+` as a friend function and not as a member function.

There's a whole discussion of this issue over at cplusplus.com:

[Binary operators as friends - why?](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/5623/)

Meyers also discusses it in his book Effective C++ IIRC.

[Quoting from the comment of geustgulkan](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/5623/#msg24881):

> For any given binary operator, it the
>   left hand object that carries out the
>   operation.
>
> Say we have a class ClassX which has
>   an overload for the + operator for
>   integers. Then if we create an object
>   of thet class (call it objx), then we
>   can say objx + 2. objx will will carry
>   out the operation and return the
>   result object of ClassX.
>
> But what happens if we say 2 + objx ?
>   The result should be the same as 2 +
>   objx - BUT integers are not classes
>   and certainly numeric literals are not
>   - so 2+objx is not possible directly.
>
> It would be a pain if we had to design
>   our code to make sure we always has
>   ojbjects of ClassX on the left hand
>   side of the + whenever we wanted to
>   add an int to it.
>
> This is where we use friend overloads
>   for operator+ for ClassX.

```
class ClassX
{

    friend ClassX operator+(ClassX objx, int i);
    friend ClassX operator+(int i, ClassX objx);
};
```

So what you probably want is:

```
class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    double weight;
public:
    Person::Person();                           //default constructor       
    Person::~Person();                           //default desctructor
    friend Person operator+(const Person &rhs, const Person &lhs);
};

Person operator+(const Person &lhs, const Person &rhs) {
     // do whatever constitutes addition here
     Person temp = lhs;
     temp.weight += rhs.weight;
     return temp;  // return copy of temp
}
```

Comment: I feel like I'm repeating myself: -1: `operator+` is **not** supposed to modify `lhs`. (BTW this isn't even possible in your example since your passing `lhs` by `const` reference) Its prototype is `Person operator+(const Person&, const Person&)`

Comment: @Job:  Sorry, wasn't paying attention - fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I only have one advise: use Boost.Operators.

```
class Person: boost::addable<Person>      // yes private inheritance
{
public:
  Person& operator+=(Person const& rhs);

private:
};
```

There are 2 advantages as far as I can see:

- No need to write boiler-plate code, and thus no chance to get it wrong ;)
- Make for a clear interface, `addable` is pretty much self-explanatory

Boost.Operators provides a reference table, which for each behavior lists the required operators that should be defined and those that will be generated automatically.

It's very handy to keep the interface compact and to inject some documentation right into the code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you made the member operator+ declaration with no intent to reference any Person-instance data: the member operator, as any member method, accepts the instance on which it is invoked as an argument.

If for some reason you need to make it a member (e.g., access to private state), you can declare it static.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Person
  {
    private:
     int age;
     double weight;
    public:
      Person();                           //default constructor       
      ~Person();                           // destructor
      Person operator+(const Person &r); //overloaded operator as member function, so only one argument is required to be passed
 };
```

Implementation :

```
  Person Person::operator+(const Person &r)
  {
      Person x;
      x.age=this->age + r.age; // this refers to the object on which the function has been invoked, P1 in this case(see below)
      return x;
  }
```

When you overload a binary operator(+ in this case) as member function, the object on which the operator is invoked is passed implicitly to the function and you need to pass only one argument explicitly

Thus your main function should be like this

```
 int main()
 {
    Person P1,P2;
    P2=P1+P2; //P1 is passed implicitly 

    //The above expression is equivalent to P2=P1.operator+(P2);
}
```

Comment: -1: `operator+` is not supposed to modify `this`. If you made it `const`, the compiler would have caught your mistake.

Comment: @Job: Thanks for pointing that out. Mine was a trivial implementation though. Now could you please remove your downvote?

Comment: Sure I will. There is still a small error, though: it should be `Person Person::operator+`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with argumentations of agsamek and sbi. I add some extra considerations

1. as you can see your class Person
   doesn't have any costructor with 2
   arguments and that's an error (but
   not yet signaled by compiler)
2. ofen when you overload one math operator you need also to overload the "operator=" and the constructor;
3. if you want to overload the plus
   operator with 2 arguments you can't
   use an instance member but you must
   use a function. I avoid to declare
   friend functions because you break
   *encapsulation* of that class (it will
   be more difficult to maintain). It's
   better to implement some "accessor
   methods" to get object's internal
   values;
4. in some compilers, an inline method needs
   declaration and definition in the
   same place (normally in .h file) so in less
   manutenable. Moreover the expansion
   of that code is at compiler
   discrection.

Next follow my solution to your question:

```
class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    double weight;
public:
    Person(){}                           //default constructor       
    Person(int a, double w) : age(a), weight(w) {}
    ~Person(){}                           //default desctructor

    int getAge() const { return age; }
    double getWeight() const { return weight; }

    const Person & operator =(const Person & rha) {
        age = rha.age; weight = rha.weight; return *this;
    }
};

Person operator +(const Person & lha, const Person & rha)
{
    return Person(lha.getAge() + rha.getAge(), rha.getWeight() + lha.getAge());
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Person p1(30,75);
    Person p2(40,80);

    Person sumOfPis = p1 + p2;  // <-- Without "operator =" this statement will use the default copy constructor

    return 0;
}
```